# Wikipedia global search (all languages), without using a third-party search engine?

Tags: privacy, search, wikipedia

Performing a search on the Japanese Wikipedia is easy:

```
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=%s
```

Now, I want to perform a search on **all** language versions of Wikipedia.

For instance when I search for [Alain Pozzuoli](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awikipedia.org%20Alain%20Pozzuoli), it must list the article in the French Wikipedia (actually the article does not exist in other wikipedias).

With Google I would use: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awikipedia.org+%s
But for privacy reasons I want to avoid that.
How to perform this search using a request to a Wikipedia/Wikimedia server?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, without querying every single Wikipedia.

Comment: @svick: It seems that no other answers are coming, so feel free to add this comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If privacy is your only concern, I would suggest you use [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com): a search engine that respects their users' privacy and that do not record any user information.

You can use a similar syntax to what you suggested:
[https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Awikipedia.org+%s](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3awikipedia.org%20%25s)

Comment: I guess it is the best solution until Wikipedia implements its own global search system.